# A proof of Hurwitz formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a question from Fulton's book (problem 8.36). My problem is in the part (a). Seems obvious that divisor is effective. but I cannot calculate the degree. I believe it uses pullback ... However, Fulton doesn't talk about it. How to solve without it? Part (b) also seemed confused.

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a nonconstant morphism of projective nonsingular curves, corresponding to a homomorphism $\tilde{f}$ of $K(Y)$ onto $K(X)$. The integer $n=[K(X):K(Y)]$ is called the degree of $f$. If $P\in X$, $f(P)=Q$, let $t \in O_{Q}(Y)$ be a uniformizinf parameter. The integer $e(P)=\operatorname{ord}_{P}(t)$ is called the ramification index of $f$ at $P$.

(a) For each Q \in Y show that $\sum_{f(P)=Q}e(P)P$ is an effective divisor of degree $n$ (See proposition 4 of 8.2)

(b)$(\operatorname{char}k=0)$. With t as above show that $\operatorname{ord}_{P}(dt)=e(P)-1$.

(c)$(\operatorname{char}k=0)$. If $g_{X}$ is the genus of $X$ and $g_{Y}$ is the genus of Y. prove that (Hurwitz' Formula)

$$2g_{X}-2=(2g_{Y}-2)n +\sum_{P\in X} (e(P)-1)$$

Comment: thanks for the correction!